# How to popup a message box when receive a notification on foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

Using swift3 with xcode 8.3 and this is a webview app.

Below is my function in ViewController.swift to handle url received from push notification

```
func redirectTo(url: String) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    MyApp.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Below is my function in AppDelegate.swift to handle didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let pushUrl = userInfo[AnyHashable("url")] as? String {
        viewController?.redirectTo(url: pushUrl)
    }
}
```

When my app running on background, it will redirect my app to url received from notification when I click on it.

However, when my app running on foreground, it will directly redirect my webview to url without doing nothing.

I know this is because every time I received a notification , it will call redirectTo function and then loadRequest.

My question is , how can I add a message box with two button, when my app running on forefround and receive a notification it will ask user to redirect or cancel ?

Comment: Just add an alert in did receive notification with two options ok and cancel, write redirect to url code on ok click. Show alert after some delay. Hope it may help you 

Comment: @Chandan I am totally a new to swift. I will try it.Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alert to get confirmation from users. Something like this

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "YOUR_TITLE", message: "YOUR_MESSAGE", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in
        // Handle your ok action
    }
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
        // Handle your cancel action
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

As the URLRequest may be expensive, you might want to implement that in background.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    MyApp.loadRequest(request)
}
```